# (Flask) How to modify list after a fetchall

Tags: python, sql, list, flask, fetchall

(sorry for my very bad english !... ^^)
Hello everyone

I make a def in my flask to keep with my fetchall a list.
But i need to add a parameters in my list to do something.
I need to add in list[4]

However, i don't know how i can do this ...

```
# Fonction récupération des comptes patients
def get_accountpatient():
    var = "SELECT id, Nom, Prenom, Tel FROM `users` WHERE Privilege = 'patient'"
    try:
        cur = bdd_login()
    except pymysql.Error as e:
        return session_out(e)
    cur.execute(var)
    list = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    print(list)
    return list

list return : ((1, 'BLOQUIAU', 'Thomas', '0669696969'), (2, 'PARAT', 'Clement', '0669696969'), (24, 'Gerez', 'Quentin', '0642181185'))
```

Python code in another fonction to call **get_accountpatient()**

```
return render_template('user_manage.html', **templateData, accounts=get_accountpatient(), sidebar=7, usermanage_div=2)
```

HTML code

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Prénom</th>
    <th>Téléphone</th>
    <th>Administré par {{prenom_user}} {{name_user}}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  {% for list in accounts %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ list[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ list[1] }}</td>
        <td>{{ list[2] }}</td>
        <td>{{ list[3] }}</td>
        <td>{{ list[4] - **I NEED TO ADD THIS LINE** }}</td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

I want this it's possible

```
((1, 'BLOQUIAU', 'Thomas', '0669696969', 'Oui'), (2, 'PARAT', 'Clement', '0669696969', 'Oui'), (24, 'Gerez', 'Quentin', '0642181185', 'Oui'))
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is to add the constant value in the SQL query:

```
sql = """SELECT id, Nom, Prenom, Tel, 'Oui' As Admin 
         FROM `users` WHERE Privilege = 'patient'
      """
...
cur.execute(sql)
```

Should you need the value to be dynamic, pass it as a parameter. Below assumes your DB-API uses `%s` for param placeholders (others may use qmarks `?`):

```
sql = """SELECT id, Nom, Prenom, Tel, %s As Admin 
         FROM `users` WHERE Privilege = 'patient'
      """
...
myvar = 'Oui'
cur.execute(sql, (myvar,))    # PARAMS MUST BE PASSED IN TUPLE OR LIST (NOT SINGLE VALUES)
```

Comment: I didn't explain but the value "oui" is not in the database ... i need to create this value with another check in another database table before implementing in my list

Comment: Wherever the value derives, you can pass it into query as parameter. And if both tables are in same database, use `JOIN`. Be sure to give fuller explanation of your problem.

Comment: Yes sorry, I forgot to mention this important thing even though I should have thought about it before

access : http://prntscr.com/rlfjhd
users : http://prntscr.com/rlfjwa

I need to know if ID in users is in my access. JOIN is better or another JOIN is good ?

Comment: I don't know where i close the ticket